# is there any solution for making 10000 concurrent web requests in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, web

I want to test my asp.net web api REST service that hosted in a HP-580dl and I want to measure the performance and response time when 10,000 simultaneous requests hit the service.

is there any way to do that in C# ?

Comment: yes. what effort have you made?

Comment: No single server is likely to ever be able to handle 10k *simultaneous* requests. Why the C# requirement? There are lots of tools for this, including `ab` (Apache Benchmark) and hosted services like https://www.blitz.io/

Answer (score 1):

Siege is a good tool for measuring load under concurrent requests: http://www.joedog.org/siege-home/

It's not written in C#, but there's no reason why it should be.

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio load testing tools provide this functionality, and can control multiple agents in cases where you want a distributed profile and/or a greater concurrency level than a single client machine can support.

[Create and run a load test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182594.aspx)